# Axios global error handler not showing modal with error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a component that manages Axios errors and shows them in a `Modal` component. I manage to store the error into the state of the error handler, but the modal does not get displayed, and the error state resets soon after.

```
import Modal from "../../components/UI/Modal/Modal";
import { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import CSSModule from './withErrorHandler.module.css';

// HOC that wrap any component that uses Axios and handle its errors
const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axiosInstance) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.catchError();
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            this.catchError();
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            axiosInstance.interceptors.request.eject( this.reqInterceptor );
            axiosInstance.interceptors.response.eject( this.resInterceptor );
        }

        catchError() {
            // Reset any previous errors
            this.reqInterceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
                this.setState({ error: null });
                return request;
            }, (error) => {
                this.setState({ error: error });
            });

            // Check for errors at response receipt
            this.resInterceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
                console.log("[withErrorHandler], response:", response);
                return response;
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({ error: error });
            });
        }

        displayError = () => {
            this.setState({ error: null });    
        }

        render() {
            console.log("[withErrorHandler], error: ", this.state.error);
            const error = this.state.error
                ? (
                    <Modal 
                        showModal = {!!this.state.error}
                        displayModalHandler = {this.displayError}>
                            <div className = {CSSModule.ErrorMessage}>
                                {`ERROR: ${this.state.error.message}`}
                            </div>
                    </Modal>
                )
                : null;

                console.log("error element", error);

            return(
                <Fragment>
                    {error}
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
};

export default withErrorHandler;
```

The `Modal` component gets following props:

- `showModal` - boolean value, and if true, the modal is displayed, while if false, it is not displayed
- `displayModalHandler` - function that is executed when the backdrop of the modal is clicked

**Wanted behavior**:
Display modal when an error occurs.

**Actual behavior**:
Modal is not displayed.

[image: Output of the console.log() functions in the code.]

It seems like the error stored in the state gets overwritten below, but I don't understand why that happens.

**SOLVED**

Had to check whether the *new state* is equal to the *old state*  and to remove the second parameter of `this.reqInterceptor`. Code below:

```
const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axiosInstance) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.catchError();
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            axiosInstance.interceptors.request.eject( this.reqInterceptor );
            axiosInstance.interceptors.response.eject( this.resInterceptor );
        }

        catchError() {
            // Reset any previous errors
            this.reqInterceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
                if(this.state.error)
                    this.setState({ error: null });
                return request;
            });

            // Check for errors at response receipt
            this.resInterceptor = axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(response => response, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                if(!this.state.error)
                    this.setState({ error: error });
            });
        }

        displayError = () => {
            this.setState({ error: null });    
        }

        render() {
            console.log("[withErrorHandler], error: ", this.state.error);
            const error = this.state.error
                ? (
                    <Modal 
                        showModal = {!!this.state.error}
                        displayModalHandler = {this.displayError}>
                            <div className = {CSSModule.ErrorMessage}>
                                {`ERROR: ${this.state.error.message}`}
                            </div>
                    </Modal>
                )
                : null;

            return(
                <Fragment>
                    {error}
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, only things that comes to my mind si, maybe you call `displayModalHandler` in Modal in componentDidMount so you set error to null and it happens so quick that you dont even see the modal render.. could you possibly share Modal implementation as well ?

Comment: @gusti I'm trying to do the same thing and your code isn't working in my app.  Do you have a link to a minimal project that uses this error handler?

Comment: @tonycpsu unfortunately not.